# Multiple Javascript Calls Merged into One

Tags: javascript

I am sure that this is a very basic question but I am using the following on my website (hostingconnections.com.au/domains.php)

```
http://secure.hostingconnections.com.au/feeds/domainprice.php?tld=.com&type=register%20&regperiod=1&format=0
http://secure.hostingconnections.com.au/feeds/domainprice.php?tld=.mobi&type=register%20&regperiod=1&format=0
```

etc..

Which produce the following:

```
 document.write('12.37');
 document.write('19.05');
```

Upon doing this 100 times (tld value changes) on one page it severly slows the page load down. How can I merge these into a single .JS file that I can specify on the page where each one will appear.

I have been pulling my hair out over this issue.

Comment: What are you using them for? `document.write()` is usually not the best choice.

Comment: Basically it is exporting a price from my WHMCS (Web Hosting Management Complete System) for domain names and displaying them on an external site (my homepage) as the WHMCS is on a subdomain. This is their API.